# Show that the following diffusion equation has **Unique solution**

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that the following diffusion equation has **Unique solution** :

$ u_t-\nabla \cdot (k( x) \nabla u)-q( x) u=F( x,t) , \ \ x\in \Omega  , \ \ t>0 $

With  Neumann  boundary condition $ \large \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \hat n}=h(x,t), \ x \in \partial \Omega \ $ and with Initial conditions:

$ u(x,0)=f(x) \ \ and \large \ u_t(x,0)=g(x) \ $

Assume $ \ k>0 \ $ and $ \ q<0 \ $.

**Answer:**

The given equation is

$ u_t-\nabla \cdot (k( x) \nabla u)-q( x) u=F( x,t) \\ \Rightarrow u_t-(\nabla k) (\nabla u)-k(x) \nabla^2 u-q(x)=F(x,t), ............(1) $

Let $ \large \ v, w \ $ be two solution of $ \ (1) \ $ .

Then, we have

$ \large v_t-(\nabla k) ( \nabla v)-k(x) \nabla^2 v-q( x) v=F( x,t) $ .............. $ (2) $

$ \large w_t-(\nabla k)( \nabla w)-k(x) \nabla^2 w-q( x) w=F( x,t) $ .............. $ (3) $

Now let $ \large \ s=v-w \ $ ,

Now if, we can show that $ s=v-w=0 \ $ , it will imply $ \ v=w \ $. (Unique solution )

But I am unable to show that $ \large s=v-w=0 \ $

**Is there any help doing in any method ?**

Answer (score 2):

As you have pointed out, the difference $s$ solves the homogeneous equation with zero boundary condition. Suppose we have a general solution $u$ to the homogeneous equation with zero boundary condition, then we can compute the $L^2$ norm of $u$ through
$$
\langle u(t), u(t) \rangle = 2 \int_0^t \langle u_t(s), u(s)\rangle ds = \int_0^t{-}\langle k \nabla u, \nabla u\rangle + \langle q u, u \rangle ds \le 0 
$$
Since the $L^2$ norm is positivem, this proves that it is equal to zero. Hence $u(t) = 0$ in $L^2.$ So the solution is unique.